# Comparison of two numbers additionally in loop iteration

Tags: python, algorithm

Assume there are numerical variables: a, b, c, d, e..., and I want to compare a and b first, pseudo code:

```
   if a > b:
       if a > b+c:
           if a > b+c+d:
               ...
           else:
               ...
       else:
           ...
   else:
       ...
```

go forward one by one, I don't want such many if-else in code, is there any algorithm method or easy way to achieve that?

Comment: Do all the `else`s do the same thing?

Comment: Do you only need the results from the comparissons, or you actually need the ´else´ statements?

Comment: Where is `d`? is there a reason you skipped it? Is the unified logic of what you are doing once a sum exceed `a`?

Comment: @yatu I actually need ```else``` to do something, and it's depends on ths results

Comment: Well then you need to write all `else` statements individually @romlym, don't you?

Comment: @TomRon Sorry, it's a typo, fixed it. And it's not the unified logic, depends on results.

Comment: @yatu Indeed if I use if-else statement, but I don't want to use the if-else, so I ask for another solution. I need to know which level 'a' is at and decide what to do.

Comment: This `know which level 'a' is at` and hence `decide what to do`, leads to multiple possible outcomes, and hence having to choose among several options or `else` statements based on the answer. So IIUC, you can compute all results before hand, but then you're left with having to wright as many `if-else` statements as different actions you want to take based on the result @romlym

Comment: @yatu Yes, but it's still more elegant (and better code design) to calculate which case is it in (i.e. "which level a is at") and then do the work accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make a list out of those variables, you can compare `a` to the cumulative sum of that list, and find the first index where it's `False`:

```
import numpy as np
b=1
c=2
d=7
e=10

a=8

x = [b,c,d,e]

np.argmin(np.greater(a,np.cumsum(x)))
```

Try it out!

Comment: very concise solution with numpy

Comment: Concise solutions are usually more readable (though using `argmin` to find the first `False` in a list is not such a good example of this),  and working with `numpy` is usually more efficient than writing loops yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a function that compare two value then use it like this:

```
def compare_int(a, b):
    return a > b


def ur_func():
    a = 17
    b = 2
    c = 3
    d = 4
    e = 10
    # ...

    compare = 0
    x = [b, c, d, e]
    for value in x:
        compare += value
        if compare_int(a, compare):
            print str(a) + " is greater than " + str(compare)
        else:
            print str(compare) + " is greater than " + str(a)
```

Comment: THANKS for your answer! I get that.

Answer (score 1):

A pseudo code to do this using a list. Please note that this is just a pseudo-code. You will have to modify it appropriately to suit your needs.

In the below solution, we try to add all parameters into a list. Since list is ordered. We can pick up the parameters in order to compare their sum with `a`.

```
a = 1000
b = 10
c = 20
d = 30
e = 40

cmpr_params = [b,c,d,e]

for i in range(1, (len(cmpr_params)+1)):
    if a > sum(cmpr_params[:i]):
        print (" a is greater a = %s, sum = %s" %(a, sum(cmpr_params[:i])))
    else:
        print (" a is lesser a = %s, sum = %s" %(a, sum(cmpr_params[:i])))
```

**Output:**

```
 a is greater a = 1000, sum = 10
 a is greater a = 1000, sum = 30
 a is greater a = 1000, sum = 60
 a is greater a = 1000, sum = 100
```

If `a`'s value were to be changed to `85`, the output will be as below:

```
 a is greater a = 85, sum = 10
 a is greater a = 85, sum = 30
 a is greater a = 85, sum = 60
 a is lesser a = 85, sum = 100
```

Comment: THANKS for your clear answer, I get it, and because of   @Itamar is the first answer so I'm gonna take that, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this and get the index at which this happens

```
a = 14
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # [b,c,d,e,f]
sum = 0;
for index, value in enumerate(arr):
    if a < sum + value:
        print (value , index)
    else:
        sum += value
        # and rest of your else code

print sum
```